# React Native Hooks - Trying to refactor from class Component to Function Component to use hooks

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I'm new in react native and I'm tryng to refactor this code below, and I think I'm doing some thing wrong here **"setSentences(item)"**, because it's not updating.
Do you know what i'm doing wrong here?

```
this.state = {
      sentences: [],
     };

{this.state.sentences.map((item) => {
  return(
    <TouchableOpacity
       onPress={() => {
       item.selected = false;
       this.setState(item); 
      }}>
</TouchableOpacity>
)}}
```

**Refactored:**

```
const [sentences, setSentences] = useState([]);

 {sentences.map((item) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          item.selected = false;
          setSentences(item);
        }}>
      </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: setSentences(prevSentences => ([...prevSentences, item]));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sentences is an array but when you show list array setSentences update array sentences. Something wrong here

```
const [sentences, setSentences] = useState([]);

 {sentences.map((item) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          item.selected = false;
          setSentences(item);
        }}>
      </TouchableOpacity>
```

I think you can use useRef to store array sentences and another state to set item

```
const sentences = useRef([]);
const [itemSentence, setItemSentence] = useState('');

 <Text>{itemSentence}</Text>
 {sentences.current.map((item) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          item.selected = false;
          setItemSentence(item);
        }}>
      </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 1):

For clear solution you have to create one method like this :

```js
const onItemPress = (itemIndex) => {
  const temp = [].concat(sentences);
  temp[itemIndex].selected = false;
  setSentences(temp);
}
```

Now, call this method on TouchableOpacity `onPress` method and pass current index to this method to modify that perticular item state as below :

```js
{sentences.map((item, itemIndex) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => onItemPress(itemIndex)}>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}}
```

And note, your state should be :

```js
const [sentences, setSentences] = useState([]);
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you need clone array sentences and get index inside
const [sentences, setSentences] = useState([]);

```
sentences.map((item:any,index:number) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          const cloneSentences =clone(sentences);
          cloneSentences[index].selected = false;
          setSentences(cloneSentences);
        }}>
      </TouchableOpacity>)
})
```